# Recursive Function incorrect output

Tags: java, recursion

Looking for help on a java assignment from school, I am trying to create a recursive algorithm that solves the following puzzle:

Given a starting position and an array of length n consisting n-1 positive numbers with the last position of the array being 0, for example:

```
{4 8 5 2 3 5 1 6 4 0}
```

The rules of the game:

> From starting position move to right equal to the value @ starting
>   position, repeat until you can no longer move to the right.
>
> Once you can no longer move to the right, move left in similar fashion
>   as you moved to the right and stop once you can no longer move to the
>   left.
>
> Now keep repeating this process.
>
> The puzzle will be solved when you have moved the last position of the
>   array holding value of 0.
>
> Otherwise the puzzle is unsolvable.

1. In the above example if we start @ first position which is '4'
2. We move to the right 4 positions ending up @ position 5 holding value 3
3. We move to the right 3 positions ending up @ position 8 holding value 6
4. We move to the left 6 positions ending up @ position 2 holding value 8
5. We move to the right 8 positions ending up @ last position holding value 0
6. since we have moved to the last position of the array, the puzzle is solvable.

I have to solve this puzzle using recursion, I have come up with the algorithm but the output I am getting false even though the puzzle is solvable.

Here is my Algorithm:

```
static boolean rightWing(int[] A, int i) //i = starting position
{

    int left=i;
    int right=A.length-i-1;

    if (A[i]<right)
    {
        i=i+A[i];
        rightWing(A, i);
    }
    if (A[i]<left)
    {
        i=i-A[i];
        rightWing(A,i);
    }

    if (right==A[i])
        return true;
    else
        return false; 

}
```

Comment: This is an opportunity for you to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger, which will be your single most valuable skill in software development.  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
static boolean rightWing(int[] A, int i) //i = starting position
{

    int left=i;
    int right=A.length-i-1;

    if (A[i]<right)
    {
        i=i+A[i];
        return rightWing(A, i);
    }
    if (A[i]<left)
    {
        i=i-A[i];
        return rightWing(A,i);
    }

    if (right==A[i])
        return true;
    else
        return false; 
}
```

Notice the return before the recursive calls to rightWing. You need this otherwise your method will always return the result of right==A[i] of the first call.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mustafa, after your suggestions I got the code working for some inputs. In addition to your suggestion I had to adjust couple of more control flow statements  (A[i]<=right&&A[i]!=0)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mustafa, after your suggestions I got the code working for some inputs. In addition to your suggestion I had to adjust the control flow statement above to following:                                                                                             (A[i]<=right&&A[i]!=0)                                                                                                                      (A[i]<=left&&A[i]!=0)

Comment: One last thing, by adding the return statement, is the code now tail recursive? Without the return statement, I believe each recursive call had to return back for the pending operations of operation at the end of the call. But, by adding the return statement we are actually returning the recursive function. Is that correct?

Comment: You are welcome Asif. As far as I can see, this is a tail recursive function because the final result (true, or false) can be obtained without having to return from every call, i.e. can be obtained by evaluating the tail/final call in the recursion chain. But Java doesn't optimize tail-recursive functions so it doesn't make a difference. Here is a good explanation of tail recursion http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/recursion/tail-recursion/.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful link Mustafa, we have one more task about the game. some arrangements of the game will result in an endless loop such as following:

Comment: {1,1,5,3,2,6,2,5,2,0 } You see in this position, if we start at first position of the array, we will keep looping between the two 5's. I tried to come up with an algorithm and used it with random arrays however I am getting stack overflow in some cases. Here is a method that I am using when I can no longer move right and start moving left :

Comment: static boolean checkImpossible(int[] B, int i, int num)    
{ 
boolean test=false;    
for (int j=i-1;j>=i-B[i];j--)
    {
    if(B[j]==num)
        {
        System.out.println("J =="+j+"I "+ i);    
        test=true;
        }
    num++;
    }   
return test;
}
    
}

Comment: static boolean checkImpossible(int[] B, int i, int num)
{ 
         boolean test=false;    
    
  for (int j=i-1;j>=i-B[i];j--)
             {
          if(B[j]==num)
                {
                System.out.println("J =="+j+"I "+ i);    
                test=true;
                }
              num++;
             }   
         return test;
}